# How to apply conditional expression filter on spark dataframe where the conditional expression is saved in the dataframe column

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark

I have many DataFrames and each of them can have separate filters to filter out data. The filters are pre-defined as well. I am planning to create a combined dataframe which will contain the filtering expression as one of the column. In this combined dataframe, I need to apply filter which is part of the data row itself. For example

If I have 3 DataFrames like this

```
val ausDF = Seq(
  ("australia", "Steve Smith", "batter"),
  ("australia", "David Warner", "batter"),
  ("australia", "Pat Cummins", "bowler")
).toDF("country", "player", "speciality")

val indDF = Seq(
  ("india", "Rohit Sharma", "batsman"),
  ("india", "Virat Kohli", "batsman"),
  ("india", "Jaspreet Bumrah", "bowler")
).toDF("country", "player", "speciality")

val engDF = Seq(
  ("england", "Jos Buttler", "bat"),
  ("england", "Joe Root", "bat"),
  ("england", "James Anderson", "bowl")
).toDF("country", "player", "speciality")
```

I can do a union to create a combined dataframe like this

```
val cricketersDF = ausDF.union(indDF).union(engDF)
```

If there is a filter dataframe like this

```
val batsmanFilter = Seq(
  ("australia", "speciality == \"batter\""),
  ("india", "speciality == \"batsman\""),
  ("england", "speciality == \"bat\"")
).toDF("country", "filter")
```

I can then join these 2 DataFrames

```
val batsmanFilterDF = cricketersDF.join(batsmanFilter, "country")
```

which gives me a dataframe with filters like this

```
+---------+---------------+----------+-----------------------+
|country  |player         |speciality|filter                 |
+---------+---------------+----------+-----------------------+
|australia|Steve Smith    |batter    |speciality == "batter" |
|australia|David Warner   |batter    |speciality == "batter" |
|australia|Pat Cummins    |bowler    |speciality == "batter" |
|india    |Rohit Sharma   |batsman   |speciality == "batsman"|
|india    |Virat Kohli    |batsman   |speciality == "batsman"|
|india    |Jaspreet Bumrah|bowler    |speciality == "batsman"|
|england  |Jos Buttler    |bat       |speciality == "bat"    |
|england  |Joe Root       |bat       |speciality == "bat"    |
|england  |James Anderson |bowl      |speciality == "bat"    |
+---------+---------------+----------+-----------------------+
```

Now, what I want is to apply the filter provided in the *filter* column to get the required result. Something similar to this

```
batsmanFilterDF.filter(col("filter"))
```

However, this gives me an error that

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: filter expression '`filter`' of type string is not a boolean.;;
Filter filter#45: string
```

So, I wanted to know is there a way to use filtering based on conditional expression using the value specified in the dataframe column?

Comment: why don't you specify the speciality in the filter dataframe, and use the speciality as a joining condition?

Comment: @mck Thanks.. The filtering condition will be created using some external tool and we will have no control over it. Moreover, the filtering condition may contain one or more columns.

Comment: @kvj, if batsmanfilter dataframe is small you can have it as an in memory collection and for a filter string by looing the collection.

Comment: thanks @SathiyanS. I thought about it but I wanted to avoid looping as there can be n number of filters and m number of countries..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, there is no way to apply a complex filter contained in a column to a dataframe. If the filter was simple, we could design a trick but you seem to say that the filters can be complex.

If the dataframe `batsmanFilter` is small, you can design and apply the filter from the driver. It would go like this:

```scala
val filter = batsmanFilter
    .collect
    .map(row => (row.getAs[String]("country"), row.getAs[String]("filter")))
    .map{ case (country, filter) =>
            "((country == \"" + country + "\") and (" + filter + "))"
    }
    .reduce(_ + " or " + _)

cricketersDF.where(filter).show
```

which yields what you seem to expect:

```
+---------+------------+----------+
|  country|      player|speciality|
+---------+------------+----------+
|australia| Steve Smith|    batter|
|australia|David Warner|    batter|
|    india|Rohit Sharma|   batsman|
|    india| Virat Kohli|   batsman|
|  england| Jos Buttler|       bat|
|  england|    Joe Root|       bat|
+---------+------------+----------+
```

The advantage of this approach is that only one filter is applied. Yet, this will only work if the `batsmanFilter` dataframe is reasonably small. If it is not, we could work something out as well but we would need to know more about the kind of filter we can find.

Comment: Thanks Oli, this definitely helps! However, I was able to create the same filter using 
    val filter1 = batsmanFilter
      .map(row => "((country == \"" + row.getAs[String]("country") + "\") and (" + row.getAs[String]("filter") + "))")
      .reduce(_ + " or " + _)
This way we can generate the filter without using collect. Do you see any issue with that?

Comment: You made spark do the computation and collected only the result. That's even better I would say. Nice ;-) Although to be honest, with a small dataframe that does not change much.